# How does the targeted musculature differ when lateral raises are done with DBs held to a front facing angle?

Tags: shoulders, dumbbells

Alfred does lateral raises with his palms facing toward each other, and the dumbbells parallel with his forward facing feet. Bob does them with his palms facing forward and the dumbbells parallel with the wall in front of him, perpendicular to his feet.

What different muscles are these two friends targeting?

Comment: You're describing 2 separate exercises. Alfred is not doing lateral raises, theyre front raises. They mainly target the front/anterior delts. Bob however is doing lat raises, targeting the side/medial delts

Comment: Argh, this is really frustrating. I wish one of the mods could help me out: I commented on an answer that is now deleted a very good clarification but I’m far too tired to reexplain it right now. Perhaps someone with enough reputation to see it could reintroduce it to the question or comment it onto the question itself?

Comment: Are you just asking what the difference is between neutral grip lat raises and supinated grip lat raises? https://youtu.be/XXyHYpAZIcU

Comment: @TylerDurden As requested, reproducing your comment from my deleted answer: “Sorry, I think you’re misunderstanding. In both cases there is a jumping Jack motion where the arms are pointing down, then away from each other to the side, and then finally perhaps even pointing more or less up to the sky. But in one case the palms begin facing each other, then face the floor, and then perhaps away from each other. In another case they are constantly facing the front of the room. Does the targeted muscles change much from this?”

Comment: In the future, feel free to submit a custom flag to the question for that sort of assistance.